# TwoWay Binding a PointCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm attempting to simulate a kind of simple CAD-like behaviour using WPF, where a polygon is drawn onto a canvas, and the points of the polygon can be moved around.

I've managed to get it so that a PointCollection property is displayed on the canvas by setting up an ItemsControl with an Ellipse for each Point in the collection. The polygon displays correctly, so I know the Binding is working Source-To-Target. I've set up some simple events to be able to 'pick up' points of the polygon, and move them around. The events work fine, and the polygon does change on the canvas. However, any changes I make to the point positions are not getting pushed to the Source Property.

Any clues on how to get the Binding to work in the opposite direction? Is this sort of thing (Two-Way binding inside ItemsControl) even possible? Or perhaps there's another approach to this!

Thanks

**XAML**

```
<Canvas Width="500" Height="300" MouseMove="MoveMouse">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyPath, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True }">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas>
                    <Ellipse Width="20"
                             Height="20"
                             Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True }"
                             Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True }"
                             Fill="Red"
                             Margin="-10,-10,0,0"
                             MouseDown="ClickPoint" />
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public PointCollection MyPath { get; set; } = new PointCollection{ new Point(10, 10), new Point(100, 100), new Point(200, 100) };

    public Ellipse selectedPoint;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MoveMouse(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedPoint == null) return;

        //Move selected point to mouse position
        selectedPoint.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement).X);
        selectedPoint.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement).Y);

        //Print out MyPath points to check if source has changed
        Console.WriteLine("");
        foreach (Point p in MyPath)
            Console.Write(p + " - ");
    }

    private void ClickPoint(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Pick up point, if no point is currently selected
        selectedPoint = selectedPoint == null ? (Ellipse)sender : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `struct Point` is a value type, and hence the Point that is used as DataContext of each item is a different instance than the one in the source collection. It should work if you use a custom MyPoint *class* in an ObservableCollection<MyPoint>.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right! Thanks @Clemens